# How Do I Control on MultiChoice AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I am using Dialog in my app to allow user to make multiple selection, Here is my code:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Build an AlertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            // String array for alert dialog multi choice items
            String[] colors = new String[]{
                    "Red",
                    "Green",
                    "Blue",
                    "Purple",
                    "Olive"
            };

            // Boolean array for initial selected items
            final boolean[] checkedColors = new boolean[]{
                    false, // Red
                    false, // Green
                    false, // Blue
                    false, // Purple
                    false // Olive

            };

            // Convert the color array to list
            final List<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(colors);

            // Set multiple choice items for alert dialog

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colors, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    // Update the current focused item's checked status
                    checkedColors[which] = isChecked;

                    // Get the current focused item
                    String currentItem = colorsList.get(which);

                    // Notify the current action
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            currentItem + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Specify the dialog is not cancelable
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            // Set a title for alert dialog
            builder.setTitle("Your preferred colors?");

            // Set the positive/yes button click listener
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click positive button
                    tv.setText("Your preferred colors..... \n");
                    for (int i = 0; i<checkedColors.length; i++){
                        boolean checked = checkedColors[i];
                        if (checked) {
                            tv.setText(tv.getText() + colorsList.get(i) + ", ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Set the negative/no button click listener
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click the negative button
                }
            });

            // Set the neutral/cancel button click listener
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click the neutral button
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            // Display the alert dialog on interface
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

And I have two queries:

1. Like I have selected Red and Purple

   (then in TextView getting output like this: `Red, Purple,`)

   **First of all I would like to remove comma (which getting with last value)**
2. I already selected Red and Purple, when i again open dialog not getting red and purple as selected by default (How can i save the state)`enter code here`, and as a result, when i am again selecting these (Red and Purple) two items, getting each item **twice in a TextView**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating your textview after the loop

And if your loop iteration reaches the length of the `checkedcolors` then donot append a comma.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Do something when click positive button
        tv.setText("Your preferred colors..... \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedColors.length; i++) {
            boolean checked = checkedColors[i];
            String colors = "";
            if (checked) {
                colors = colors + colorsList.get(i) ;
                if (i != checkedColors.length - 1) {
                    colors = colors + ", ";
                }
            }
        }
        tv.setText(tv.getText() + colors);
    }
```

Yor textview will be updated only once, so you wont be getting each item twice in the TextView.

For saving the state you have to use `SharedPreference`.

For saving into preference use this

```
       SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("yourColor",isChecked);
        editor.commit();
```

And to retrieve

```
        boolean isChecked = preferences.getBoolean("yourColor");
```

Comment: @Oreo Glad I could help :)

Comment: can you help me in creating Step Views -- like Step 1 form > Step 2 form and Step 3 (Finish) ?

Comment: @Oreo Steps for imlementing the `SharedPreference`??

Comment: no @Boss Like in many apps to create an account or book an appointment or reserve a room, we have to fill three different forms (Step 1 - Profile) > (Step 2 - Reservation) > (Step 3 : Review Detail)  I hope now you can understand my requirement

Comment: @Oreo And what is the problem you found implementing that?

Comment: i don't have any idea how to create that kind of program and what's the best approach of doing it ?

Comment: @Oreo I would suggest using Fragment

Comment: do you have any sample code so please share with me or can you write a small sample for me .. ?

Answer (score 5):

Please try this and improve structure of your code so that it can be managed efficiently.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private TextView txtSelected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
        txtSelected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_selected);

        final ArrayList<ColorVO> colorList = new ArrayList<ColorVO>();
        // String array for alert dialog multi choice items
        final String[] colors = new String[]{
                "Red",
                "Green",
                "Blue",
                "Purple",
                "Olive"
        };
        // Boolean array for initial selected items
        final boolean[] checkedColors = new boolean[]{
                false, // Red
                false, // Green
                false, // Blue
                false, // Purple
                false // Olive

        };

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                // make a list to hold state of every color
                for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                    ColorVO colorVO = new ColorVO();
                    colorVO.setName(colors[i]);
                    colorVO.setSelected(checkedColors[i]);
                    colorList.add(colorVO);
                }

                // Do something here to pass only arraylist on this both arrays ('colors' & 'checkedColors')
                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colors, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        // set state to vo in list
                        colorList.get(which).setSelected(isChecked);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                colorList.get(which).getName() + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                builder.setCancelable(false);

                builder.setTitle("Your preferred colors?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        txtSelected.setText("Your preferred colors..... \n");

                        // save state of selected vos
                        ArrayList<ColorVO> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < colorList.size(); i++) {
                            ColorVO colorVO = colorList.get(i);
                            colors[i] = colorVO.getName();
                            checkedColors[i] = colorVO.isSelected();
                            if (colorVO.isSelected()) {
                                selectedList.add(colorVO);
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedList.size(); i++) {
                            // if element is last then not attach comma or attach it
                            if (i != selectedList.size() - 1)
                                txtSelected.setText(txtSelected.getText() + selectedList.get(i).getName() + " ,");
                            else
                                txtSelected.setText(txtSelected.getText() + selectedList.get(i).getName());
                        }
                        colorList.clear();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // make sure to clear list that duplication dont formed here
                        colorList.clear();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // make sure to clear list that duplication dont formed here
                        colorList.clear();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ColorVO {
        private String name;
        private boolean selected;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }
    }
```

Solved all of your queries :

### **1. Like I have selected Red and Purple**

=> Check for index of element, If it is last then do not attach comma.

### 2. I already selected Red and Purple, when i again open dialog not getting red and purple as selected by default (How can i save the state)

=> save state using vo in your default array.It will be saved until your activity is not destroyed.

### 3. when i am again selecting these (Red and Purple) two items, getting each item twice in a TextView

=> Clear list so that values do not get duplicated.

Comment: no doubt @MamataGelanee  that you have provided great and complete solution of my requirement... but Boss's solution is also good... for me you both provided best answers.. so i can't accept your solution because i already accepted Boss's but i ticked as useful...

Comment: can you help me in creating Step Views -- like Step 1 form > Step 2 form and Step 3 (Finish)

Comment: Like in many apps to create an account or book an appointment or reserve a room, we have to fill three different forms (Step 1 - Profile) > (Step 2 - Reservation) > (Step 3 : Review Detail)  I hope now you can understand my requirement @MamataGelanee

Comment: my bad luck few days ago practo was using, but now they removed it .. i am searching for image for more clarity