# Prevent AlertDialog from auto closing on NeutralButton Click???

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to override the behavior of alert dialog box on clicking of neutral button or negative button to not auto dismiss .

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do something and close dialog
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Clear All", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do something but not close dialog           
        }
    });
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
            // do something
            } else {
            // do something else
            }
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

The expected behavior of negative button here is : on clicking of "*Clear All*" it should just clear the selection that's all and not automatically close the dialog.? But Android alertDialog automatically closes the dialog, on click of **NegativeButton** or **NeutralButton**. Any way to override this behavior

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323605/how-do-i-control-on-multichoice-alertdialog

Answer (score 1):

So i was able to achieve this with adding *dialog.setOnShowListener()* after dialog.create() and before dialog.show()

```
    builder.setNeutralButton("Clear All", null);
    builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button clearAll = builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // do something but don't dismiss
                       for(int which=0; which<checkedItems.length; which++){
                        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Loop solves one problem, Problem: on clicking *clear all*, the checkbox UI in alert dialog doesn't change. So run a final loop to change the UI, making all checkbox unchecked.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323605/how-do-i-control-on-multichoice-alertdialog

Comment: i did a loop and i was able to change the state of all the checked items.