# How to add dynamic checkbox in dialog box according to json array length?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, dynamic, dialog

I want to add the dynamic checkbox inside dialog box with submit and cancel button and the checkbox should become according to the size of JSON array from API

```
  private void callDoctorTiming() {
    String request_url = GlobeStrings.BaseUrl + "/doctor-admin/apis/app.php?api=doctorTiming";
    pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pd.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.Loading));
    pd.show();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    final String response = null;
    final String finalResponse = response;
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST,
            request_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Log.e("@@TimeApi", response);
            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray jsonArray = objData.getJSONArray("time");


                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){



                        String time = jsonArray.getString(i);
                        Log.e("@@Time", time);



                    }

                  //  profileModel.setAvailability_time(profileModel.getAvailability_time() + "");
                   /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    onDateTime = obj.getString("data");
                    Log.e("@@ondateTime", onDateTime);*/
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Log.e(TAG, "error in api " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    ) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("doctor_id", "" + doctorID);
            params.put("available_date", "01-01-2020");
           // params.put("available_date", "" + date);
            return params;
        }
    };
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
}
```

here in response, I am getting time inside response I want to add dynamic checkbox with time as I am getting from the response

here is my response from API

```
{
"error": false,
"data": {
    "time": [
        "10:00 am-04:00 pm"
    ]
},
"message": "success"
 }
```

here is my dialog layout :

```
  void showTimeDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.time_layout);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    TextView tv_pcolse = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_pcolse);
    TextView tv_submit = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_submit);
    final CheckBox checkbox_time1 = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_time1);
    checkbox_time1.setText("");

    tv_pcolse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    tv_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkbox_time1.isChecked())
                profileModel.setAvailability_time(profileModel.getAvailability_time() + "" + 
         checkbox_time1.getText());
            else
                profileModel.setAvailability_time(profileModel.getAvailability_time() + "");

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

here is my xml of dialog :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="340dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_design">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Whattimedoyouacceptonlinevisit"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#444141"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
<CheckBox
    app:buttonTint="@color/dark_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textColor="#888282"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_time1"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FF68B6DA"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Submit"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Close"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_pcolse"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to add checkbox according to time in response its dynamic

Comment: you should define a ViewGroup to add an item to it and here is your Checkbox. and last thing do you want to add or just make it visible?

Comment: I want to add checkbox in dialog with set text of multiple times

Comment: inside response, I need to add

Comment: I think i should remove the checkbox from layout

Comment: adding can means more than one but if you want just one, so just use checkbox.setVisibility(View.Visible)

Comment: no, I don't need static just one

Comment: OK then make it invisibile and them visible when you want in your code

Comment: inside for loop, I want to add the dynamic checkbox

Comment: if time is more than one than I need according to this

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView to set Dynamic Checkbox

Here is full example of show checkboxes in RecyclerView :-https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple.php

Comment: I want to add in the dialog box

Comment: It is not like that as I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Alert Dialog with multi choice option

See the references :

1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32324244/12650715

2) https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-alertdialog-multichoice.html

3) https://www.android-examples.com/show-create-alertdialog-with-multiple-choices-in-android/

NOTE: Convert the json array to string array first